# Command to find duplicate files in different directories

Tags: files, scripting

I am looking for a tool, utility, or script that reports if two directories contain the same files (recusrively), but not necessarily in the same subdirectories.

I'm begun the tedious and long-overdue process of organizing my digital photos from over the years. As they are mostly from phone dumps, there's a number of deletions that I make, while skipping over the few I want to keep. Because I was rather disorganized, I have multiple duplicate files from several different disks and devices. I want to eventually trash all of these old discs, but not before I am certain that I have all the files I want to keep.

I am looking to learn two things:

1. Confirm which files on old, disorganized backup discs are present in the well-organized directory, so I can safely delete or trash the old backups, and
2. Learn which files on backup disks do not exist in the well-organized directory, so that I can copy them into the new directory.

Is there any command, utility or script that does this?

Comment: Are all directories (you want to find duplicate files in) available at the same time? I'm asking because "I want to eventually trash all of these old discs" may mean you want to connect disks one by one. I guess nobody keeps all old media connected. But the strategy may depend on whether or not you can access all the data without manually disconnecting/connecting devices.

Answer (score 0):

`fdupes` can find duplicate files by MD5 and byte comparison in multiple directories and you can even pick the good one and let it delete all the others. Just repeat for every backup disk.